# Can't connect to [QBChat Instance] connect with User, in Quickblox

Tags: chat, quickblox

I am using Quickblox Api, for chat and video chat. iOS. And I am using the latest version of the API

When I try to Make a video call, 
most of the times i don't get video, only audio. 
i get video on both ends 1 out of 15 times. 
3 out of 10 times video on one end.

very weird. I have good internet connection. connecting to chat users are receiving the call. Can seem to find out the issue.

Comment: Hello! Please post your issue on github https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/issues with console logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending sometime to find the issue, I received and help from Quickblox Help Center. 
If your face such Behavior on the API

1.Make Sure that you set Delegate Methods in viewDidLod, not view did appear or etc. For Ex:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [[QBChat instance] addDelegate:self];
    [QBRTCClient.instance addDelegate:self];
    [QBSettings setCarbonsEnabled:YES];
}
```

Use Breakpoints to find out if they are getting called, once you make or receive calls.

2.Make Sure that your Calling methods are correct. An array containing Users must not equal to currentUser.ID.

```
NSInteger currentUserID = [QBSession currentSession].currentUser.ID;
    int count = 0;

NSNumber *currentUserIndex = nil;
for (NSNumber *opponentID in opponentsIDs) {
    if ([opponentID integerValue] == currentUserID) {
        currentUserIndex = @(count);
        break;
    }
    count++;
}
if (currentUserIndex) [opponentsIDs removeObjectAtIndex:[currentUserIndex intValue]];
QBRTCSession *session = [QBRTCClient.instance createNewSessionWithOpponents:opponentsIDs
                                                         withConferenceType:QBRTCConferenceTypeVideo];
NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ @"key" : @"value" };
[session startCall:userInfo];
if (session) {
    self.currentSession = session;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openDialogSeg" sender:self];
}
else {
    [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"You should login to use chat API. Session hasn’t been created. Please try to relogin the chat."];
}
```

}

3. Check View Layout, size and width. make sure they are set correctly.